# turtle setup with even spacing in xcor and ycor

Tags: netlogo

I want to setup turtles in NetLogo that are evenly distributed from min-xcor to max-xcor every 1 patch. Currently, what is clear is that turtles can be created with random-xcor and random-ycor. Please help.

Comment: starlogo (a cousin of netlogo) has the ability to do a setxy kind of thing. Forget the syntax, but you could say something like "setxy who 0"

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`sprout`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sprout). `sprout` tells a patch to create a turtle directly on top of it. So, for example:

`ask patches [ sprout 1 ]`

will create exactly one turtle on every patch. You can use `with` to restrict the patches if you want do this in only part of the world:

`ask patches with [ -6 < pxcor and pxcor < 10 ] [ sprout 1 ]`

You can also include initialization code for the turtles just like you can with `create-turtles` and `hatch`:

`ask patches [ sprout 1 [ set color red ] ]`